# Is it possible to create a 'logic system' equivalent to humans?

Tags: research, applications

I've heard of AI that can solve math problems. Is it possible to create a 'logic system' equivalent to humans that can solve mathematics in the so called 'beautiful' manner?  Can AI find beauty in mathematics and solve problems other than using brute force? Can you please provide with examples where work on this is being done?

Answer (score 2):

There is of course a vast amount of work in the area of Automatic Theorem Proving, but most of it is simply concerned with proof, rather than human notions of beauty, elegance, parsimony etc.

There has however been some work in this general area over the years:

- Douglas Lenat's famous [AM](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1983/AAAI83-059.pdf) ('Amateur Mathematician').
- Douglas Hofstadter's [NUMBO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_Concepts_and_Creative_Analogies#Chapter_3:Numbo:_A_Study_in_Cognition_and_Recognition) program for number sequence extrapolation.
- A range of publications by [Simon Colton](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sgc/cv.html)
- [Shalosh B. Ekhad](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/ekhad.html), the automated proof assistant for Artificial Combinatorics created by Doron Zeilberg and credited by him as a co-author on numerous papers.